# Create VCF card with picture in vba

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, vcf-vcard

I have a database in MS Access with info of contacts and a separate folder with all pictures. I'd like to create vcf cards with embedded pictures. The code to extract info from the database and to read the picture works but the code to create the card doesn't (probably because of the base64). Could you help me?

```
Private Function encodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

Dim objXML As Object
Dim objNode As Object

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
encodeBase64 = objNode.text

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub createVCF()

Dim objXML As Object
Dim objNode As Object
Dim encode As String
Dim image_bin() As Byte

'read image
file = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "photo.jpg"
Open file For Binary Access Read As #1
ReDim image_bin(LOF(1) - 1)
Get #1, , image_bin
Close #1

'encode
encode = encodeBase64(image_bin)

'create vcf
Open CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "card_test.vcf" For Append Access Write As 2
Print #2, "BEGIN:VCARD"
Print #2, "VERSION:3.0"
Print #2, "N;CHARSET=WINDOWS-1252;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;" & "Doe" & ";" & "John" & ";;;;;"
Print #2, "NAME;CHARSET=WINDOWS-1252;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" & "John" & " " & "Doe"
Print #2, "NOTE;CHARSET=WINDOWS-1252;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" & "From MS Access"
Print #2, "TEL;Work:" & "1234"
Print #2, "TEL;Cell:" & "4321"
Print #2, "EMAIL;Work:" & "john.doe@doe.com"
Print #2, "ADR;WORK:;;" & "Building A" & " - " & "2B" & ";;;;"
Print #2, "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64:" & encode
Print #2, "END:VCARD"
Close #2

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you, Arno

Comment: Can you make clearer where exactly the problem in your code is?

Comment: Outlook doesn't show the picture when I open the vcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in the VCard specification, you need to add a leading space to each folded (wrapped) line in the VCard file.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3.2

This applies to your Base64 image data in this case.

To achieve that replace all the LF (linefeed) in your Base64 data with a LF followed by a space.

```
'encode
encode = Replace(encodeBase64(image_bin), vbLf, vbCrLf & Space(1))
```

While we are at it, the code replaces LF with CRLF too, as that is what the spec asks for. - Although it does not make any difference regarding Outlook.

Comment: It works. It makes difference regarding Outlook. Thank you very much.